# Как получить ответ от сервера применяя json

Tags: python, json, requests

Я отправляю запрос на сервер:

```
data = {'user': i, 'text' : b}
resp = requests.get('http://10.27.1.9:5000/newmessage', params=data)
```

я хочу получить в консоли ответ сервера в виде:

Никнейм: текст (датавремя)

Как мне все это сделать?

Comment: Ну мы же не знаем, что вам сервер отвечает. Проще всего, если что-то есть в `resp.json()`, оттуда проще всего было бы вытащить. Это просто словарь.

Comment: @CrazyElf сервер мне отвечает [{'user': 'da', 'text': 'da', 'timestamp': '2021-15-11 15:33:34'}, {'user': 'da', 'text': 'da', 'timestamp': '2021-15-11 15:33:50'}]
Как мне это структурировать в формат: Никнейм: текст (датавремя)

Comment: @CrazyElf я попробовал сделать вот так но почему то все равно не работает
data = r.json()
name = data["user"]
ms = data["text"]
tim = data["timestamp"]
print(name)
print(ms)
print(tim)

Comment: @imadjf что не работает? Чему равняется у вас name после name = data["user"]?

Comment: привидите пример что должно получится: {'da':'2021-15-11 15:33:34'} либо {'da': ['da', '2021-15-11 15:33:34']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер возвращает список, вот и обрабатывайте его как список:

```
resp = ...
for message in resp.json():
    print(f"{message['user']}: {message['text']} ({message['timestamp']})\n")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я понимаю что с моей формулировкой сложно понять суть вопроса, но вы как-то поняли. Хотел бы спросить ещё, как мне сделать так чтобы раз в n секунду запрашивать у сервера сообщения. И выводить только новые?

Comment: Раз в n секунд - это зависит от структуры приложения. Простой способ - цикл с операцией `sleep(n)`. Что касается вывода новых, то это зависит от того поддерживает ли API сервера получение начиная с какого-то сообщения (или вообще какую-то фильтрацию, по дате например). Если не поддерживает и возвращает все, то нужно тогда хранить у себя ранее прочитанные и при повторном получении их не показывать.